# What does EE10 or EE15 mean for transformer cores?

Tags: transformer, component-selection, buying

I have been studying about transformers.  When I went to buy some transformer cores from Alibaba for research, I saw different names like EE 15 transformer.

What does the EE10 or EE15 transformer code mean? Does that apply to any core?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

EE cores are named with their dimensions.

The following is from EE10's datasheet from TDK:

[image]

As you can see, "10" here indicates the width in millimetres of a half core.

<s>Correct</s> Full name includes other dimensions as well. For example, when you see an EE10 it can be EE10/5/5 or EE10/5.5/5 (depending on the manufacturer) which includes the height of a half core (5.5 mm) and depth (~5 mm).

So yes, EE10, EE15 and similar names indicate the core shape and dimensions. But always check the manufacturer's datasheet as some of them may have slightly different dimensions such as the ones I mentioned above.

Comment: Important to also note: an EE core is one that has two E-shaped halves that get glued, taped, or clamped together. This is as opposed to an EI core, where you have one E-shaped part and one I-shaped part. There are other core shapes, but those are the only ones I know of named for the letters they resemble.

Comment: @Hearth LL, FL and UI

Comment: @Hearth Also FF and TU